# How to open XML document properties window in Visual Studio?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

MSDN documentation refers to [XML document properties window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255817%28v=vs.120%29.aspx). How to open it?

When right-clicking in solution explorer in VS2012, it opens "File properties", but the properties are not that described in the MSDN...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click at the XML file in the editor and click `Properties`

Answer (score 0):

**Open** XML file ==> XML properties are shown 
**Select** XML file in Solution Explorer ==> file properties are shown

Visual studio 2017 used